# Creating Virtual Interface Linux

Tags: linux, bash, network-programming, debian

My goal is to simulate more than one IP interface using just a physical interface, for do that I tried using this alias

```
Ifconfing ethX:1 <IP>
```

But when I try to send a packet over that interface I see the IP source the same as the original, and real,  Ethernet interface. Then I tried to use TAP interface but I was unable to "link" them with my physical one, I notice them can communicate each others but can not ping (`ping -I tap0  <ip real IF>`) the original one.
It is still valid if I create a bridge with all them.

I would like avoid to install many Virtual Box as I need but what I want is exactly what it do: build a new virtual interface and bridge it with a real one in order to have more IP interface attached at one physical.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A network interface in Linux can have multiple ip addresses bound to it. Natively. See the man page of `ip` command (`man 8 ip`) for subcommand `addr`.

Comment: You should also investigate iptables.

Comment: @fork0 : I need differents MAC addresses as well, yes IPTABLES could be a solution but I looking for a easier way, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try macvlan. It allows you to create a virtual interface with a unique MAC address and you can assign IP addresses specifically to that virtual interface.

See: http://jim.studt.net/depository/index.php/notes-on-linux-s-macvlan-module